# single UPDATE query to modify multiple columns on multiple conditions SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008

i'm having a sql table consisting of three columns `ID`,`KEY` and `VALUE`
now i want to update this table's specific rows based the `KEY` column associated with that row.

i tried following `UPDATE` query to update multiple rows in a single update query.

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET VALUE=(CASE WHEN [KEY]='KEY1' THEN 'VALUE 1 MODIFIED'
                WHEN [KEY]='KEY3' THEN 'VALUE 3 MODIFIED'
          END)
```

but this query updated the unmatched rows with `NULL` value as shown in below fig.

[image]

is their any other way to write single `UPDATE` query to modify different columns based on different conditions?

Comment: You need to include an `ELSE VALUE END` in the `CASE` statement. If no `when` matches, the `CASE` returns null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET VALUE=(CASE WHEN [KEY]='KEY1' THEN 'VALUE 1 MODIFIED'
                WHEN [KEY]='KEY3' THEN 'VALUE 3 MODIFIED'
            ELSE ''
          END)
```

This will set the unmatched rows to an empty string '' but you can set a default value if you want. But if you want that column to retain its value then you could so something like this.

```
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET VALUE=(CASE WHEN [KEY]='KEY1' THEN 'VALUE 1 MODIFIED'
                WHEN [KEY]='KEY3' THEN 'VALUE 3 MODIFIED'
            ELSE VALUE
          END)
```

Comment: I'll prefer this:
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET VALUE=(CASE WHEN [KEY]='KEY1' THEN 'VALUE 1 MODIFIED'
                WHEN [KEY]='KEY3' THEN 'VALUE 3 MODIFIED'
          END) where KEY in ('KEY1','KEY2') 
as this query will only update required two records. So, if the KEY column is indexed, it will be faster. Retaining old value in Else part is avoided, causing better performance.